# How do I know the offset for each limit?

Tags: sql, apache, http, web-applications, pagination

When I use `LIMIT` to make pages of results, how do we usually know the offset i.e. which page should be retrieved for each request?
Via cookies?

Comment: @meagar:You mean: `?page=2`?

Answer (score 1):

Via a query string parameter, traditionally. URLs typically include a `?page=3` to request page 3, like you'll see all over Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=2&sort=newest

This is something you absolutely should *not* do through cookies. The URL should include everything necessary to navigate to the given page. Consider a user bookmarking page three of your results, or trying to link somebody else to the page they're looking at: Using cookies to store pagination data breaks these situations completely.

Comment: @fdreger No, it's not. In the real world, you absolutely should not do it. This isn't "preaching", this is advice you *need* to follow if you want to build apps that don't break in the eyes of your user. Storing the *page number* in the session, decoupled from the URL, doesn't solve *any* problems, it only introduces them.

Comment: Just because your experience is focused on one type of development (dealing mosty with PHP frameworks, RoR, Django - traditional, action oriented frameworks) does not mean that the world ends there. The fact that *you* have no idea about how JavaServer Faces, ASP.NET, Vaadin or Errai work and solve real-life problems - does not make them inferior. Or better. Just different.

Comment: @fdreger:Hi!  I think that meager means that storing the page number as part of the session object is discouraged.Not that using a session object to store session data in general is a bad idea.At least this is how I understand his answer.In this context the problem of not being able to bookmark the pages seems plausible to me.

Comment: @jim: bookmarkable urls are important in public-facing, document oriented pages with a well defined focus (/pictures/cats?page=45). As soon as you have an intranet application with five or six data grids visible at once, users' expectations change. Nobody expects to be able to bookmark a state of a form that has hundreds of controls in a couple of tabs - people are accustomed to the fact, because this is how gmail, facebook, igoogle etc. all work (some state is bookmarkable, some is not).

Comment: @meager: a single example? Imagine a form with a "company" field. When user starts to type text into the field, a floating non-modal popup comes up, showing a data grid with matching companies and their details (the actual use-case is: "User knows that the company has 'stork' in it's name, but is not sure of other details").

Comment: @fdeger No part of that suggests anything but the query string to me. If you need to load "live" data without a full-page refresh, I would use the hash fragment. The use case is "The user want's to link their fellow employee to the data grid he's looking at". Of course, your method of screenshotting the browser or saying "Hey Bob, walk across the building and look at this" is also good, if you don't care about your users. Your approach *may* have been "correct" in the same way using "goto" was correct, but it really isn't, any longer. We know better, and there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Usually via request parameters in action frameworks (RoR, ZF, Cake, Django) and via state of the session in component frameworks (Prado, JSF, ASP.NET). Session is usually associated with request by a cookie.

Using session to store current page is quite common in business-oriented applications, where state of the gui might be very complicated and the practically of being able to bookmark a page - limited.

Comment: "Common" is subjective, and "common" doesn't mean "correct". This remains a horrible practice and *breaks* your URL bar. Extenuating circumstances always exist, but telling a new user that this is valid, knowing nothing about their situation, is *wrong*. The correct decision is *always* to use the query string for what it was designed for, and to deviate when you actually have enough experience to know that deviation is required.